Measure contact between two meshes
I'm trying to implement a Python script that calculates the contact between two meshes that intersects in certain areas and save a VTK file with the calculated information. In particular, I would like to colour one of the meshes with the magnitude of penetration that the other mesh exerts on it.
I have calculated distances between two meshes with scipy and Pyvista and saved the result in a VTK file with the following code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import pyvista as pv

# Paths to meshes
mesh1_path = "/path/to/mesh1.stl"
mesh2_path = "/path/to/mesh2.stl"

# Read meshes
mesh1 = pv.read(mesh1_path)
mesh2 = pv.read(mesh2_path)

# Compute distance to meshes
fieldname = "distance"
dist_mesh = mesh2
tree = cKDTree(mesh1.points)
d_kdtree, idx = tree.query(dist_mesh.points)
dist_mesh[fieldname] = d_kdtree

# Visualize mesh2 colored with distances
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(dist_mesh, clim=[min(0, np.min(d_kdtree)), np.max(d_kdtree)],
                 scalars=fieldname, smooth_shading=True,
                 opacity=1, cmap="jet")
plotter.show()

# Save to disk
dist_mesh.save(f"/tmp/{fieldname}.vtk")

It occurs to me that I could take negative distances in all those cells of the mesh that are inside the other, but seeing that the d_kdtree variable only contains positive values and contact areas are coloured in blue (i.e., zero distance), I understand that this is not the method I am looking for.
I've been looking in the scipy and Pyvista documentation but can't seem to get anything to fit. Is there any way to measure the penetration of one mesh over another?

tolerance = 5 #custom
indices = tree.query_ball_point(dist_mesh.points, tolerance)
unique_indices = np.unique(np.concatenate(indices))
if unique_indices.size > 0:
    point1 = np.array(mesh1.points[int(unique_indices[0])])
    point2 = np.array(mesh1.points[int(unique_indices[-1])])
    depth_of_intersection = np.linalg.norm(point1 - point2)

This will probably give you the  penetration of one mesh over another.
